# Aligning Different sized Text Vertically

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having a bit of trouble aligning some items.
Next to each-other as per the Design i've tried everything I know off and im not really to sure how to go about googling this.

Also if you have any alternative way's of doing this I'd appreciate it.(The whole side Tabbed thing)

[image: Website]

[image: Design]

So what I did is the Side bar is Positioned absolutely

```
.side-tab{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,2,25,0.9) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%);
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 30em;
    padding-bottom: 15em;
}
```

It's going to be tabbed for the Big Carousel with different carousels and headers and such

```
<div class="side-tab row">
  <div class="tab-number col-md-6">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'PRO')" id="defaultOpen">01</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'CREAT')">02</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TIM')">03</button>
  </div>
    <div class="tab-title col-md-6">
        <button class="tablinks-title" onclick="openTab(event, 'PRO')" id="defaultOpen">PROFESSIONAL</button>
        <button class="tablinks-title" onclick="openTab(event, 'CREAT')">CREATIVITY</button>
        <button class="tablinks-title" onclick="openTab(event, 'TIM')">TIMELY</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So How would I Align the "Title's" Next to the Numbers if the font size's are different, Or go about this whole thing in a more "Appropriate" manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the heights and line-heights of the buttons. Something like this:

```
.tablinks,
.tablinks-title {
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
.tablinks {
    font-size: 50px;
}
.tablinks-title {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: ooh right I forgot about line-heights Works perfectly thanks man!